# Expand variable in sed expression

Tags: regex, sed

I need expand a variable into a sed expression, but the variable value is a variable name including `$`.

Line to clean, it's the first line (and this first line changes on several fails, for `$otheVarNameN`):

```
<?php $someNameVar = '27tfs%6<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<... more code ... ?><?php
```

I tried this code, and it works fine if I use the  variable name and escape `$`:

```
$hack = "$someNameVar"

// I need use $hack var for expanded, work how line below 
sed -i.bak -E "s/(<\?php \$someNameVar.*\(?>)(<\?php)/\2/" hack.php
```

When I try to modify the code to pass the variable name in a for loop:

```
sed -i.bak -E "s/(<\?php ${hack}.*\(?>)(<\?php)/\2/" hack.php

sed -i.bak -E "s/(<\?php \$${hack}.*\(?>)(<\?php)/\2/" hack.php
```

Comment: Looks like your system has been hacked. You need to find out why they were able to inject those variables into the code, fix the security hole and reinstall the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the shell parameter expansion operator to perform string replacement, to replace `$` with `\$`.

```
hack='$someNameVar'
sed -i.bak -E "s/(<\?php ${hack//$/\\$}.*\(?>)(<\?php)/\2/" hack.php
```

From the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
>   The *pattern* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. *Parameter* is expanded and the longest match of *pattern* against its value is replaced with *string*. If pattern begins with `/`, all matches of *pattern* are replaced with *string*.